# rRNA colony PCR amplification not working

Tags: pcr

We used some universal primers to amplify rDNA in a certain isolated bacterial specie. The problem is that rDNA PCR is not amplifying.

Primers were working well in other strains of same bacterial specie.

Do you know what could be happening? Maybe strain-specific PCR inhibitors? This strain was successfully amplified using ERIC PCR.